# Macro to calculate the difference in hh:mm:ss

Tags: vba, excel, date, excel-formula

I want to calculate the difference in hh:mm:ss between Now and column E. They both appear in format dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm. With the code I have written below, it only takes into consideration the hh:mm and not the days. So, if they have 2 days difference in wont add to the hours +48. The code is below:

```
With ws1.Range("N2:N" & lastrow1)
.Formula = "=TIME(HOUR(NOW()),MINUTE(NOW()),SECOND(NOW()))-TIME(HOUR(E2),MINUTE(E2),SECOND(32))"
End With
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `=(NOW()-E2)` and apply a custom format `[hh]:mm:ss`. The brackets around `hh` will do the trick.
If you rather need a number of hours, multiply by 24 as @Kerry Jackson suggested.
The logic behing date/time values is that 1 day = 1, so

- 1 hour = 1/24
- 1 min = 1/1440  '(that is 24*60  )
  etc...

Comment: I actually did that exact thing, but I wanted to avoid doing it in two rows so as to cut the size of the macro...

Comment: That's very neat - I did not know of the trick of putting brackets round the hh.

Answer (score 4):

Put this in a module

```
    Public Function DateTimeDiff(d1 As Date, d2 As Date)


        Dim diff As Double
        diff = ABS(d2 - d1)

        DateTimeDiff = Fix(diff) & Format(diff, " hh:mm")


    End Function
```

Then use

```
=DateTimeDiff( NOW(), E2 )
```

as the formula in the worksheet.

You might want to add some validation on the dates and return an error message if they are not valid.

Comment: Nice, you could used `diff = Abs(d2 - d1)`,   instead of `If d2 > d1 Then diff = d2 - d1 Else diff = d1 - d2`

Comment: I also realised that `diff = diff - days` is redundant, as the later Format function only takes the time part anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for a number which is the number of hours, or are you looking for text?
If you want the number of hours, try just subtracting the dates, and multiplying by 24, so the formula would be `=(NOW()-E2)*24`.

Comment: I want it to appear as number but in the form of a date

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Function timeElapsed(ByVal target_cell As Range) As String
Dim hours As Long, minutes As Long, days As Long
If target_cell.Value = 0 Then Exit Function
x = DateDiff("n", target_cell, Now())
days = Format(Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(x / 1440, 0), "00")
hours = Format(Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown((x - (days * 1440)) / 60, 0), "00")
minutes = Format(Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown((x - ((days * 1440) + (hours * 60))), 0), "00")
timeElapsed = CStr(days) & " " & "days" & " " & CStr(hours) & ":" & CStr(minutes)
End Function
```

And use as function with the result as below:

[image: Result]

So you code becomes:

```
With ws1
    .Range("N2:N" & lastrow1).FormulaR1C1 = "=timeElapsed(RC[-9])"
End With
```